# Getting oracle error ORA-12541

Tags: database, oracle

I am working on this project of partitioning of database. Till now i managed to configure the listener locally and to configure it for one machine. But this machine isn't able to see my listener, and i get the error ORA-12541. Can anyone help me please.
If any one wants any further details please don't hesitate to ask.

tnsnames.ora:

```
PROJETSGBDD_AFIFA=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=192.168.200.103)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVICE_NAME=orcl)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora:

```
LISTENER=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=sylma)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

The oracle SID is tpbdd.

Comment: Show you tnsnames.ora, listener.ora and ORACLE_SID. What is your Oracle version?

Comment: PROJETSGBD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.200.172)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = sgbd)
    )
  )

LOCAL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = tpbdd)
    )
  )

PROJETSGBDD_AFIFA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.200.103)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
This is tnsnames.ora

Comment: LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = sylma)(PORT = 1521))
  )  This is listener.ora

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle

Comment: the Oracle SID is TPBDD? Isn't that French for "Travaux pratiques Bases de données" ? In other words is this school work?

Comment: @Benoit in fact it is. It is more of faculty work :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, based on your listener.ora, try adding this to your tnsnames.ora:

```
tpbdd = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=sylma)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=tpbdd)))
```

And then try connecting with:

```
sqlplus your_user/your_password@tpbdd
```

Hope that helps.